# Why do regression through the origin when taking residuals of response variable against fitted values regressed against residuals of added var?

Tags: regression, residuals, diagnostic

I know my title may be a little off, but I'm not sure how to describe the terms I'm talking about in a more concise manner so if there is one do let me know.

I finished working through an exercise in a textbook I'm using for personal study *(Applied Linear Statistical Models 5th ed - Kutner et al)*. The final part of the question asked me to obtain my full fitted regression function by separately regressing both $Y$ and $X_2$ on $X_1$ and then regressing the residuals of those sets of regression functions. Symbolically, I need to first obtain the regression function of:

$$e(Y|X_1) \sim e(X_2|X_1)$$.

Where $e(Y|X_1) = Y - \hat{Y}(X_{1})$ and $e(X_2|X_1) = X_2 - \hat{X_{2}}(X_1)$.

This would give me an expression of the form:

$$\widehat{e(Y|X_1)} = \hat{\beta_{e}}[e(X_2|X_1]\ (*)$$

Once doing this I could then use that relationship to obtain my original full regression function:

$$\widehat{e(Y|X_1)} = \hat{Y} - \hat{Y}(X_{1}) = \hat{\beta_{e}}[X_2 - \hat{X_{2}}(X_1)]$$.

I'm having an issue reconciling the line $(*)$ in my description. Specifically why are we now regressing through the origin? I ask this because up to this point in the text regression through the origin has been given short shrift in the book. There was a quick section dedicated to it, which at the end it was said that we "don't really bother with it and usually stick to regression through an intercept". But now here in a comment in this later section about added variable plots it is just dropped in. I should mention it is dropped into a "comment" at the end of the section, so still given not much attention. I suppose that if you are obtaining the full regression function you don't have to worry about this.

I guess I now have two questions:

$1)$ Why do we use regression through the origin in this scenario?

$2)$ What kind of scenario would present itself where we would have to "build" the regression function from these sets of residuals instead of taking the full regression? Or is it just to quench a theoretical curiousity?

Comment: Provided the first regressions had an intercept, the residuals for the second will have mean zero so that no intercept will be needed.

Comment: That actually is the case. I could see why what you're saying makes sense.

Comment: You may also google Frisch Waugh Lovell or FWL on this site for related discussion.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thank you for the assistance.